# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll'

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, wamp

I'm trying to use php threads but I receive this message when I run my file in the console: **Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.10/ext/php_pthreads.dll** and if I open it on my localhost it shows the error **Class thread not found**.

I'am using wamp server, I have Windows 10 64 bits.
I use php version 7.2.10
I downloaded the php threads dlls from here: **https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/pthreads/3.1.6/**

I already put the phtreadVC2.dll in the folder `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10`,
the php_phtreads.dll in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10\ext`
And edited the php.ini file in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10`
and I even tried editing the php.ini file located in `C:wamp64\bin\apache`.

In my phpinfo() I have enabled *Thread Safety*
And I have the compiler: **MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017)**

Answer (score 0):

I have not actually used this extension but can I suggest you try these changes to what you have done.

Putting the `php_pthreads.dll` into `c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.10/ext/` sounds correct.

However, you should try putting `phtreadVC2.dll` into `C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apachex.y.z/bin` where `x.y.z` is the version of Apache that you are using. This is where PHP under Apache will probably look for this DLL.

If you might want to use `php_pthreads.dll` under the PHP CLI then also edit `C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.10/php.ini` and add the `extension=` parmeter in here as well as this is where the CLI will probably look for it.

Now to make sure you are adding the extension into the correct `php.ini` that  PHP under Apache will find its `php.ini` us the menus on wampmanager. Thats the green `W` icon in the System Tray by doing

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

This should open the editor on the correct `php.ini` file, the one that controls PHP when used under Apache. Add the extension into here.

If you want to use the CLI, then you will also have to make the same edits to the `php.ini` file in `c:/wamp64/bin/phpx.y.z/php.ini` this is the `php.ini` that controls what the PHP CLI loads.

Restart Apache once you have made all these changes and see how it goes.